# How to fix “bottom overflowed by 4.0 pixels flutter” error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-fragments, model-view-controller

I'm using a package which is built on Flutter. An error occurs on some of the android devices. I'm having trouble in solving this issue and look out some solutions in which people were prefering to use a widget called "Expanded" but it doesn't work. Do i need to wrap something? If yes, how to do it? And what does this error means?

[you can see the error in this image here, click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rElcF.jpg)

````
    final addProductToCart =
        Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false).addProductToCart;
    final currency = Provider.of<AppModel>(context, listen: false).currencyCode;
    final currencyRate = Provider.of<AppModel>(context).currencyRate;
    var salePercent = 0;

    if (item == null) return Container();

    double regularPrice = 0.0;
    var productImage = width * (ratioProductImage ?? 1.2);

    // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
    if (item.regularPrice != null &&
        item.regularPrice.isNotEmpty &&
        item.regularPrice != '0.0') {
      regularPrice = (double.tryParse(item.regularPrice.toString()));
    }

    final gauss = offset != null
        ? math.exp(-(math.pow(offset.abs() - 0.5, 2) / 0.08))
        : 0.0;

    /// Calculate the Sale price
    bool isSale = (item.onSale ?? false) &&
        Tools.getPriceProductValue(item, currency, onSale: true) !=
            Tools.getPriceProductValue(item, currency, onSale: false);
    if (isSale && regularPrice != 0) {
      salePercent =
          (double.parse(item.salePrice) - regularPrice) * 100 ~/ regularPrice;
    }

    if (item.type == 'variable') {
      isSale = item.onSale ?? false;
    }

    if (hideDetail) {
      return _buildImageFeature(
        context,
        () => _onTapProduct(context),
      );
    }

    var priceProduct = Tools.getPriceProductValue(
      item,
      currency,
      onSale: true,
    );

    /// Sold by widget
    Widget _soldByStore = item.store != null && item.store.name != ""
        ? Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2),
            child: Text(
              S.of(context).soldBy + " " + item.store.name,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          )
        : Container();

    /// product name
    Widget _productTitle = Text(
      item.name + '\n' ?? '',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.apply(
            fontSizeFactor: 0.9,
          ),
      maxLines: 2,
    );

    /// Product Pricing
    Widget _productPricing = Wrap(
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          item.type == 'grouped'
              ? '${S.of(context).from} ${Tools.getPriceProduct(item, currencyRate, currency, onSale: true)}'
              : priceProduct == '0.0'
                  ? S.of(context).loading
                  : Config().isListingType()
                      ? Tools.getCurrencyFormatted(
                          item.price ?? item.regularPrice ?? '0', null)
                      : Tools.getPriceProduct(item, currencyRate, currency,
                          onSale: true),
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline6
              .copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              )
              .apply(fontSizeFactor: 0.8),
        ),

        /// Not show regular price for variant product (product.regularPrice = "").
        if (isSale && item.type != 'variable') ...[
          const SizedBox(width: 5),
          Text(
            item.type == 'grouped'
                ? ''
                : Tools.getPriceProduct(item, currencyRate, currency,
                    onSale: false),
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .caption
                .copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.6),
                  decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                )
                .apply(fontSizeFactor: 0.8),
          ),
        ]
      ],
    );

    /// Product Stock Status
    Widget _stockStatus = _buildStockStatus(context);

    /// product rating, Hide rating for onSale layout.
    Widget _rating = (kAdvanceConfig['EnableRating']) &&
            (kAdvanceConfig['hideEmptyProductListRating'] == false ||
                (item.ratingCount != null && item.ratingCount > 0)) &&
            !(showProgressBar ?? false)
        ? SmoothStarRating(
            allowHalfRating: true,
            starCount: 5,
            rating: item.averageRating ?? 0.0,
            size: 10.0,
            color: kColorRatingStar,
            borderColor: kColorRatingStar,
            label: Text(
              item.ratingCount == 0 || item.ratingCount == null
                  ? ''
                  : '${item.ratingCount}',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .caption
                  .apply(fontSizeFactor: 0.7),
            ),
            spacing: 0.0)
        : Container();

    /// Show Cart button
    Widget _showCart = (showCart &&
            !item.isEmptyProduct() &&
            item.inStock != null &&
            item.inStock &&
            item.type != "variable")
        ? IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart, size: 18),
            onPressed: () {
              String message =
                  addProductToCart(product: item, context: context);
              _showFlashNotification(item, message, context);
            })
        : Container(width: 30, height: 30);

    /// Show Stock status & Rating
    Widget _productStockRating = Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _stockStatus,
                    _rating,
                    const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            top: -8,
            child: _showCart,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget _productImage = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: productImage),
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(18 * gauss, 0.0),
            child: _buildImageFeature(
              context,
              () => _onTapProduct(context),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        /// Not show sale percent for variant product (product.regularPrice = "").
        if (isSale &&
            (item.regularPrice?.isNotEmpty ?? false) &&
            regularPrice != null &&
            regularPrice != 0.0 &&
            item.type != 'variable')
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(12))),
              child: Text(
                '$salePercent%',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .caption
                    .copyWith(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                    .apply(fontSizeFactor: 0.9),
              ),
            ),
          ),

        /// Show On Sale label for variant product.
        if (isSale && item.type == 'variable')
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(8))),
              child: Text(
                S.of(context).onSale,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );

    Widget _productInfo = Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        _productTitle,
        _soldByStore,
        const SizedBox(height: 5),
        _productPricing,
        const SizedBox(height: 2),
        _productStockRating,
      ],
    );

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _onTapProduct(context),
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: maxWidth ?? width),
            width: width - 6,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, right: 4),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
              // border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
              // boxShadow: [
              //   const BoxShadow(
              //     color: Colors.black12,
              //     offset: Offset(0, 1),
              //     blurRadius: 2,
              //   ),
              // ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                _productImage,
                _productInfo,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (showHeart && !item.isEmptyProduct())
            Positioned(
              top: 5,
              right: 5,
              child: HeartButton(product: item, size: 18),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I can see there's _*productTitle* with 2 lines, make the height of the widget such that it can fit 2 lines, or use `FittedBox` as parent. Check details [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Expanded](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or flexible widgets, they will only occupy the space available and won't overflow